# For compact $A$, $\inf\{\varrho(y,x) : y \in A\}=\varrho(a,x)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I need help with prooving that if non empty $A$ $\subset(X,\varrho)$ is compact, then:

$(\forall x \in X) (\exists a \in A)  \inf\{\varrho(y,x) : y \in A\}=\varrho(a,x) $

I found this solution:

$\varrho_{A}(x) =  \inf\{\varrho(y,x) : y \in A\}=\lim_{n} \varrho(y_{n},x)$ for some sequence $y_{n} \in A$.

We pick subsequence $y_{n_{k}}\rightarrow a$ and then:

$\varrho_{A}(x) = \lim_{n}\varrho(y_{n},x)=\lim_{n} \varrho(y_{n_{k}},x)=\varrho(a,x)$

I don't get this solution. Is there any other way to prove it? 
Also, wouldn't it be enough if $A$ was closed, not compact? The way of proving that $\inf\{\varrho(a,b): a\in A, b\in B\}=\varrho(A,B)$ for compact $A$ and $B$ would be similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389532/is-my-proof-correct-minimal-distance-between-compact-sets?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

> $\varrho_{A}(x) = \lim_{n}\varrho(y_{n},x)=\lim_{n} \varrho(y_{n_{k}},x)=\varrho(a,x) $

This solution seems to be OK.

> Is there any other way to prove it?

Yes. If a point $x\in X$ is fixed then $\varrho(x, a)$ is a continous function on a compact set $A$, therefore it attains its infimum at some point $a\in A$.

> Also, wouldn't it be enough if $A$ was closed, not compact?

No. Let $(X,\varrho)$ be a $\Bbb Q$ endowed with the standard metric, $A=\{a\in\Bbb Q: a>\sqrt{2}\}$, and $x=0$. Then $A$ is a closed subset of the space $X$, but the distance from the point $x$ to a set $A$ is not realized by a point $a\in A$.

> The way of prooving that $\inf\{\varrho(a,b): a\in A, b\in B\}=\varrho(A,B)$ for compact $A$ and $B$ would be similar?

Yes.

Comment: OK, but why can we say that the distance from the point x to a set A is equal to $lim_{n}\varrho(y_{n_{k}},x)$ and why we have to pick a subsequence?

Comment: @sarnow Put $A_\varrho=\{\varrho (y,x) : y\in A\}$. So we can pick a sequence $\{\varrho_n\}$ of elements of the set $A_\varrho$ such that $\{\varrho_n\}$ converges to $\inf A_\varrho$. Then we remark that for each $n$, $\varrho_n=\varrho(y_n, x)$ for some point $y_n\in A$. The obtained sequence $\{y_n\}$ may be not convergent itself, but, since it is contained in a compact subset $A$ of a metric space $X$, it should contain a convergent subseqence.